# In a browser environment, is it possible to obtain list of SSL certificates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

In order to connect to a third party application, I have to give my users the capability to select one of their installed `SSL client certificates` and transfer it to the third party which is used by the application server. (My web application does not require SSL, it is the third party that require SSL certificates).

It seems to me that access to this list of certificates is `only possible by the browser itself when connecting to a service that require SSL`. Is it possible to launch the same dialog box through Javascript or is there any way for a web application to browse the SSL store of the end-user ?

If it is not possible, can I simply open a file dialog box and upload the client certificate as any standard file ?

I have to support any browser from IE9 and no plug-ins are allowed in our application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If it is not possible, can I simply open a file dialog box and upload the client certificate as any standard file ?

Firstly, that's not the way SSL/TLS client authentication works at all. It's simply not a matter of uploading the certificate. The private key matching the certificate is used to sign some content (in the `CertificateVerify` TLS message) during the TLS handshake. That's what performs the authentication.

Coming back to your main question, for security reasons, the SSL/TLS stack is handled outside the scope of the JavaScript code. Selecting the client certificate is part of that.

You could potentially have some sort of API to let the JavaScript code access some of the cryptographic features of the browser (and [there has been work in this area](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/)). However, there would be security considerations to take into account.

Even if certificates only contain public information to some extent, that doesn't mean it's public information that is to be distributed to anyone in the world, at least not necessarily in conjunction with the act of browsing any website.

If you had the ability to list the user's list of certificate from the JavaScript code sent by your server, you'd certainly have the ability to send that list back to yourself almost transparently with an Ajax call. While some people are concerned about the privacy implications of being tracked by cookies, being tracked by which client certs you may have takes this to another level (e.g. Subject DN with `CN=John Smith` and Issuer DN with `CN=Department/Ministry of Health/Defence`: that would be a bit of a giveaway).

> My web application does not require SSL, it is the third party that require SSL certificates.

Here, you're not saying whether that third party is accessed directly by the user's browsers, or if you expect the users to delegate their credentials for you to interact with that third party (without direct user involvement).

If the users have direct access to that third party (via another request), their browser should prompt them for the certificate they with to use.

If it's about credential delegations, that's another problem entirely, since users you never give you the private key for their own client certificate to be able to sign in their name. (It's might be technically possible for users to just give you their PKCS#12 file, for example, but it defeats the point of putting up in place this sort of authentication in the first place).

There has been work done about authentication delegation with certificates using [proxy certificates (RFC 3820)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3820). Essentially, your EEC (End-Entity Certificate) is used as a mini-CA, despite not having the CA flags, to issue a short-lived certificate with the remote party will accept. This sort of mechanism is generally not well integrated in browsers.

Another, more realistic approach, would be to look into the world of SSO, SAML and Shibboleth, for example. That does work with existing browsers, but the overall architecture is a bit different (so you'll need to discuss that with the third party).

Comment: Yes, it is a problem of credential delegations. The requirement is to let the user select of one its client certificate and share it to the third party.

Comment: Client certificates is simply not the way to go, then. You could look at stuff like [MyProxy and related browser add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grid-proxy-manager/) for proxy certificates, but that requires some effort for all parties to be integrated with that anyway. (Most servers don't accept proxy certificates by default.)

Answer (score 2):

The certificate isn't part of the DOM, so no, this won't be possible.

Comment: What about an ActiveX on IE? I wouldn't be so flat

Comment: AFAIK, you can do a few things that are not strictly "DOM" from JavaScript in the browser. Client certificates are just a different problem.

Comment: How about [WebCrypto](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/)? It has discovery/enumeration capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

> In a browser environment, is it possible to obtain list of SSL certificates in JavaScript?

The [WebCrypto](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) API allows you to discover some things, like shared and derived keys. But looking at their charter and use cases, its not clear to me if they allow enumeration and discovery of certificates.

I see it was discussed in the past and an issue was raised. Here's the discussion: [Crypto-ISSUE-15: Discovering certificates associated with (private) keys](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webcrypto-comments/2012Oct/0022.html). But I can't find anything on Issue 15 in the [WebCrypto Tracker](http://www.w3.org/community/webcryptoapi/track/issues).

Also see [Will the WebCrypto API allow discovery/enumeration of certificates?](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webcrypto-comments/2015Jun/0000.html) question on the [WebCrypto Mailing list](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webcrypto-comments/). Hopefully there will be a simple, YES/NO answer.

But don't be surprised if its not available through WebCrypto. The browser security engineers have a particular way of looking at things, and that usually does not include client certificates. Client certificates would effectively stop MitM attacks (see, for example, [Origin Bound Certificates](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity12/sec12-final162.pdf)), and browsers don't make stopping MitM a priority. Instead, they are OK with mishandling credentials like passwords; and they opt for a One Time Password (OTP) using [U2F](https://fidoalliance.org/specifications/overview/).

In a reality stranger than fiction, the browsers will even (1) use [Public Key Pinning for HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7469), and then (2) break a known good pinset because the user was phished! You can't make this stuff up...

Comment: "*browsers don't make stopping MitM a priority*": that's a bit unfair, there have been a few attempts at solving these problems over the past few years (e.g. HSTS, trying to provide a better UI, EV certs, ...), although not all of them are necessarily done that well or for the right reasons. It's just that it's generally a very difficult problem to solve. In my experience (a few years back), most users (even reasonably IT literate ones) found dealing with client certs too confusing or a pain (besides the potential privacy issues). They can work well, but I can't see them generally applicable.

Comment: @Bruno - They claim that phishing a user is a valid use case due to [Priority of Constituencies](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-design-principles/#priority-of-constituencies). I took exception to the ***Overrides*** written into [Public Key Pinning for HTTP](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/websec/current/msg02280.html), and voiced it on the IETF mailing lists (sadly, too late): *"Its
just not clear to me (at the moment) how a known good pinset can be
broken to facilitate proxying/interception in a proposed standard for
a security control that's supposed to stop that kind of funny
business."*